# Magento 2 Plugin / After in response All api as json in webrest Module

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to create a Plugin / After method for all Api response return in json format  in web rest Module Magento 2

Comment: Why you cannot parse JSON object to array?

Comment: for that need to require location of file and override that file , I think use plugin is good option